# refering to a line containing a column-wise calculated value

Tags: bash, awk

I want to print, for selected pattern, only the rows with minimum value for the sum of squared columns 7,8 and 9 (as in script below, which I run as $ script.sh patterns.txt). My script prints the last row for the certain pattern and I would like to print only the line that contains minimum. How could I refer to that line?

Below is input and desired output.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
grep -E -wr $line input.txt| awk '{ min=($7^2)+($8^2)+($9^2);} FNR==NR  {if (($7^2)+($8^2)+($9^2)<=min) min=($7^2)+($8^2)+($9^2);} END {print $0}' >> output.txt
done < "$1"
```

input

```
-3.79 43 18.6279 16.5936 -1.33 CAN  1 10 100  
-3.79 43 18.6279 16.5937 -1.33 CAN  2 20 200  
10.51 -66 1.71937 -9.93556 1.20 CAS 5 50 500  
10.51 -66 1.71937 -9.93556 1.21 CAS 4 40 400  
10.51 -66 1.71937 -9.93555 1.20 CAS 6 60 600  
-9.41 38 17.751 16.7401 -0.25 CASC  12 20 400  
-9.41 38 17.751 16.7401 -0.53 CASC  13 50 500  
-9.41 38 17.751 16.7401 -0.25 CASC  12 20 400
```

output

```
-3.79 43 18.6279 16.5936 -1.33 CAN  1 10 100  
10.51 -66 1.71937 -9.93556 1.21 CAS 4 40 400  
-9.41 38 17.751 16.7401 -0.25 CASC  12 20 400
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, the part `only the rows with minimum sum of columns 7,8 and 9`

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to make the arithmetical operation sound simpler since the exact mathematical operation is easily changeable. I edited the question now.

Comment: But still the expected output is not clear. How you derive them? Can you explain each of those line in the output made it? on what basis? Pick the exact value and exact condition

Comment: I derive it as in the script above, min=($7^2)+($8^2)+($9^2).

Only the rows which have the same column $5 are selected because that's the pattern that grep, e.g. minimum is calculated for all lines that contain CAN and that gives the first line of output.

Comment: Since you are using `awk` anyway, use awk to read the data and perform the regex. Simpler

Comment: you mean for reading instead of grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk                     '{v=$7^2 + $8^2 + $9^2} 
  !($6 in a) ||  v<a[$6] {a[$6]=v; line[$6]=$0} 
  END                    {for(k in line) print line[k]}' file


-3.79 43 18.6279 16.5936 -1.33 CAN  1 10 100
10.51 -66 1.71937 -9.93556 1.21 CAS 4 40 400
-9.41 38 17.751 16.7401 -0.25 CASC  12 20 400
```

for finding the minimum you need to set the initial values, here we're checking whether the key has been encountered before or not.

this is the critical condition  `!($6 in a) ||  v<a[$6]` we set/change the minimum value if it's the first encountered for the key (i.e. initial value to compare the rest against) or less than the current minimum.

Comment: Thanks but I need minimum value, in that case the default value of 0 can't be used, so I don't know how to modify this script to give minimum.

Comment: fixed now, sorry didn't pay attention at first.

Comment: It all works, I'd just like to understand it. So v<a[$6] is the part that checks whether the key has been encountered or not (and that chooses the minimum)?